# Marklogic order by ascending returns incorrect sort order

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm using MarkLogic Server (Enterprise Edition) 7.0-6.3 and wanted to sort the following data in ascending order, but the collation that I used not doing the job correctly.

Query:

```
for $result in ("A, 105.1", "A, 105.5", "A, 105.31", "A, 29") 
order by $result ascending collation "http://marklogic.com/collation//AS/MO"
return $result
```

Result:

```
`A, 29
 A, 105.1
 A, 105.5
 A, 105.31`
```

Here you see the 3rd & 4th position of the result order is incorrect. I'm not sure if its a Marklogic bug with the  MO. Help required to find the solution. Thank you.

Collation used:

- MO (Specifies numeric ordering.)
- AS (variable characters are shifted (ignored) according
  to the variable-top setting.)

Comment: If you put 0's on the end of the first two items in your sequence then they are sorted as you are expecting. I recommend you reach out to MarkLogic Support to understand if this is the intended behavior or a bug.

Answer (score 2):

collation specifies considering sequential 'digits' as numeric, not decimals. Reguardless of ignoring variable characters.  01.102 will sort after"01.2" ->   "01" == "01" , "102" > "2"

Example:

```
for $result in ("01.102", "01.2", "01.200", "01.20") 
order by $result ascending collation "http://marklogic.com/collation//AS/MO"
return $result
```

correctly produces

```
01.2
01.20
01.102
01.200
```

a 2 'key' numeric sort,

A="01", B=(2,20,102,200)

Comment: Thank you DALDEI. I'd like to know if MarkLogic supports any collation for decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired result:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

for $result in ("A, 105.1", "A, 105.5", "A, 105.31", "A, 29") 
order by fn:substring-before($result, " ") , xs:float(fn:substring-after($result, " ")) ascending
return $result
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. Sorry I have mentioned a sample use-case. Real data may not have a space(" ") in between. Are there any collation specific for Decimal sorting.

Comment: @Meg I do not know of one offhand. I recommend you reach out to your MarkLogic account team or MarkLogic support. Offhand, for real data you could also use a regular expression to split out a decimal number from the rest of the string and achieve the same effect with little difficulty. Or, better yet, you could harmonize your data as it comes in to put strings and numbers in separate fields which would make this type of sorting a breeze.